# Find slow method iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, debugging

I have an application that when it launches in Airplane mode it hangs. The application has a large set of code. I have added breakpoints in many areas and have been unable to determine the method or line of code that is causing the slowness. In visual studio using C# when an application is running you can hit pause and the debugger will be at the location of code currently executing during that moment. When hitting pause in xcode, the debugger stops in assembly code.  What can you guys recommend to find the line of code or method that is causing slowness in my app?

Comment: Check out http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: Hitting the pause button is never going to be a reliable way of profiling code. Instead, you can use real profiling tools. [Read this.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode)

Comment: I think internally that's what the Time Profile in Instruments does. It sort of pauses execution and records the stack trace for all threads every millisecond or so (that's configurable though). It's much better than doing it in person though.

Answer (score 3):

Instruments is the the right tool for the job. Exploring the call tree will tell you where your program is spending most of the time. It's quite intuitive even if you don't have much experience with it.

Also, as other have suggested you can check out [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode).

Comment: Thats true for performance issues but the wording of the question title is a bit premature.  If it's just hanging it could be for a variety of reasons.  Matter of preference, I prefer throwing out a console statement first.

Comment: With Instruments it takes a few seconds to get the specific call the code is blocked in. I get the `NSLog` point, and you can indeed use it as a helper, but you can't base your whole debugging on it. Not in this specific instance at least.

Comment: Sure is enough debugging sometimes, especially if it's a simple issue like this could be.  I believe that Instruments is always the best choice for you but not for everyone/every situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSLog strategically and note the last console output shown.

Doesn't matter how large your codebase is if you narrow it down like a binary search you'll have at most log(n) (no pun intended) number of debugging statements.

Comment: that's kind of a caveman approach. A profiling tool is what's needed here.

Comment: I think it depends on the issue. Using NSLog in many cases could very likely find the issue. If you see in the console:
 - Starting up...
 - Doing A...
 - Doing B...
 - Doing C that shouldn't take long...

Then nothing happens, that is at least a pretty good indication C isn't doing what you'd expect.

Comment: I agree with Lee Whitney use of NSLog. Rather than wasting time with implementing and integrating a profiling tool I too have successfully debugged problems with my code with in minutes using nlogs. call it whatever its just as good method.

Comment: @SamBudda implementing and integrating? Have you ever used instruments? You have to press **one** button to launch it and you can see which **method call** the application is spending most of the time on in seconds, not even minutes.
I'm not against the old beloved *printf-debugging* as a whole, but in this specific case is like hammering a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: SO War!  No, JK.  Seriously, many ways to slice an apple...

Comment: I agree. NSLog is definitely not the right tool for the job if you don't know what you're looking for. Sure you can discover what you don't know with more log statements but if you're doing that, you might as well use Instruments. Logging also won't tell you that the reason you're blocked is because your thread was waiting. Seriously, use Instruments. It's built exactly for this reason.